# For loop won't stop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I've made an array that is between [0,1000], and I've printed it.  Next step is to arrange the array using switch statements into five different cases 0 to 199, etc.  When trying to do so the `for` loop won't stop.  I tried putting a `printf` after `countOne` in case 1, no printout occurs either.

Any suggestions

Thanks for your help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int n;
int arraySize;
int randN;
int rand();

int countOne = 0;
int countTwo = 0;
int countThree = 0;
int countFour = 0;
int countFive = 0;
int countSix = 0;
int *p;
int *p1;

int main()
{
    printf("What is the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //MAKING THE N-size ARRAY

    int array[n];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        randN = rand() % 999;
        array[i] = randN;

        p = (int*)malloc(i * sizeof(int));
        p[i] = array[i];
    }

    //SORTING THE N-size ARRAY

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", array[i]);
    }

    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    p1 = (int*)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    p1[0] = countOne;
    p1[1] = countTwo;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        switch (i) {
          case 1: 
            for (i = 0; array[i] >= 0 && array[i] <= 199; i++) {
                countOne++;
            }
          case 2:
            for (i = 0; array[i] >= 200 && array[i] <= 399; i++) {
                countTwo++;
                return countTwo;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HERE IS MY CODE AS OF CURRENT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

int n;
int arraySize;
int randN;
int rand();

int countOne = 0;
int countTwo = 0;
int countThree = 0;
int countFour = 0;
int countFive = 0;
int countSix = 0;
int *p;
int *p1;

    printf("What is the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

//MAKING THE N-size ARRAY

    int array[n];
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {
            randN=rand() % 999;
            array[i]=randN;

            p=(int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int));
            p[i]= array[i];

    }

//PRINTING THE N-size ARRAY  

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           printf("%i\n", array[i]);
        }

//SORTING THE N-size ARRAY

int j;
for (j = 0 ;  j < n ; j++)
    {
        switch(j)
        {
           case 1:
                for(i = 0  ; array[i] >= 0 && array[i] <= 199; i++)
{
                countOne++;
                return countOne;
                }
           case 2:
                for(i = 0 ; array[i] >= 200  && array[i] <= 399; i++)
                {
                countTwo++;
                return countTwo;
                }
        }
    }
```

HERE IS THE PRINT OUT:

What is the size of the array
3
823
7
347
There is 0 integers between 0 and 199
There is 0 integers between 200 and 399

Comment: why are you reallocating `p` each iteration? You know you are leaking memory, right?

Comment: Your `switch` statement has a ton of problems.

Comment: Looks like the whole code does...

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do here.  Perhaps you could clarify more what you are trying to accomplish?  Show some example output or what the final array variable contents should be?  You have some real issues with your for loops and the boundary conditions (you could walk off the end of the array), and you're using the same loop variable for both the inner and outer loop.  There's way too much wrong here to help without further explanation. :-(

Comment: Your code is a mess. Maybe try commenting each line with what you think it's doing so people can see what you're trying to accomplish and where you're going wrong?

Comment: First off, get rid of literally every instance of `p` and `p1`: you're not using them and you're not freeing them, so you're leaking memory without even accomplishing anything.

Comment: Can you specify more clearly as to what you mean by 5 different cases? It really is not clear as to what your objective is. Just show us a sample input and a corresponding desired output.

Comment: Move all these global definitions to the body of the main function. The first part is fine except for the `p[i] = array[i];` that has a type mismatch. The rest is baffling: *Next step is to arrange the array using switch statements into five different cases 0 to 199, etc.* is an obscure statement, and the code is even worse... we do not understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: FWIW, it's because your inner for loop is resetting the value of `i` back to 0, so it's causing your outer loop to start all over.

Comment: First case in switch probably wants a return or a break or something?

Comment: @jszackmeister I am trying to sort my array of [0,1000].  By sort I mean count how many integers in my array are between [0,199], [200,399] ect

Comment: @VHS I am trying to sort my array of [0,1000]. By sort I mean count how many integers in my array are between [0,199], [200,399] ect

Comment: @chqrlie I have moved my variable initializations within the main function.  p[i]=array[i] works fine, I had to do this to dynamically allocate memory for the array that was built.  before I had p[i]=array and p malloced my values weren't being saved for the print.  Please explain what you mean by  type mismatch, because this corrected my problem.

Comment: @user7117719: actually `p[i]=array[i]` is not a type mismatch, it is undefined behavior: you are storing the integer beyond the end of the array allocated by `malloc()`. You allocate an array of `i` integers whose legal index values are `0` to `i-1`, `p[i]` refers to an invalid entry.  Furthermore, you reallocate a new array for each iteration in the loop, losing the previous one.

Comment: @user7117719: I reformatted your code for readability, study the difference and use this style, it won't fix the bugs but it makes the code easier to understand.  You have many more problems in it.

Answer (score 0):

The program has many problems.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_ints(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *pa = a, *pb = b;
    return (*pa > *pb) - (*pa < *pb);
}

int main(void) {
    int i, n;
    int stats[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    printf("What is the size of the array?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //MAKING THE N-size ARRAY
    int *array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int *saved = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    if (array == NULL || saved == NULL) {
        printf("cannot allocate arrays\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int randN = rand() % 999;
        saved[i] = array[i] = randN;
        stats[randN / 200] += 1;
    }

    printf("initial array contents:\n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //SORTING THE N-size ARRAY
    qsort(array, n, sizeof(*array), compare_ints);

    printf("sorted array:\n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d values between %d and %d\n", stats[i], i * 200, (i + 1) * 200 - 1);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // do whatever else you are supposed to with array and saved
    //...

    free(array);
    free(saved);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks very elegant. Will review over. Point of my task is write the algorithm twice using a for loop for one try and a switch for the other